# Singleton class with smart pointers and destructor being called

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a singleton class such that when all pointers to the class go away the destructor is called.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    uint8_t str[50]; //some random data
    MyClass() {LOG("constructor Called"); }
    ~MyClass() {LOG("destructor Called");}
    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &Get();

private:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> instance;
};

std::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClass::instance=NULL;


std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &MyClass::Get()
{
    if (instance == NULL)
    {
        instance= std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
        return instance;
    }
    return instance;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &p1 =MyClass::Get();

    printf("We have %" PRIu32, p1.use_count());
    if (1)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<MyClass> &p2 =MyClass::Get();//this should not  
                                                     //  create a new class
        printf("We have %" PRIu32, p1.use_count());  //this should be two...
        printf("We have %" PRIu32, p2.use_count());  //this should be two...
        //when p1 goes out of scope here it should not call destructor
    }
    printf("We have %" PRIu32, p1.use_count());

    //now destructor should be called
    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not work as the static instance is a smart pointer and never goes out of scope, hence the destructor is never called.

What I would like to do is when the static instance is first created to return this instance of a smart pointer and then every call there after return a copy of this smart pointer.

Comment: It's not "dumb." Don't just add words, add actual details. Define "does not work" - what does it do and what did you want it to do? Please also read what constitutes a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A std::weak_ptr is what you're looking for.

By changing the instance to be a weak_ptr, it does not count as an owner to the shared pointer; meaning that once all other references have been released the object is destroyed.  That said, it does make your "Get" function a little more complex, in that you must attempt to get a shared_ptr from the weak ptr, then on success return it, or on failure create a new one, re-assign instance to that ptr and return.

You can find more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

As a separate note, the destructor of your static member will be called, just not before main returns.  Most people accept this feature of a static since once main returns they don't really care what happens as long as the application doesn't crash   (although statics using other statics tends to result in exactly that)

Comment: The weak_ptr did fix the code.   However I found that the smart pointers require a heap (new called internal to smart pointer implementation). I am now debating on if there is a better method for having shared pointers which does not require heap.

Comment: @Trampas it sounds a little like you're worrying about things that you don't need to.  For starters, wanting your static variable to be deleted in the way you describe is rare - most people are happy with it being freed after main. Not wanting to use any heap space, is - well, you're not going to be able to do this create/destroy on demand without doing so.

Comment: You can do this by mixing in a `std::optional` and a custom deleter to the shared_ptr, though I'm baffled as to why you think you want such a thing.

Comment: So on embedded designs I often create a class for a driver, for example a UART.  With low power designs when the UART is enabled the power consumption goes up.  So I wanted to use shared_ptr such that when objects were done with UART it is deleted.   This worked great using shared_ptrs except for two things, first is that smart pointers need heap. Second is when I allocate the UART class I pass new a static address where to place object (again trying to avoid heap allocations).  The issue I have is when newlib deletes the object it sometimes (not all the time) causes a hard fault.

Comment: I should also mention that most embedded designs have a heap, but no real memory management. For example most of my designs if you allocate from heap, it is never freed. That is heap can only grow.  However at the same time most all my designs never use heap as it keeps code deterministic, keep in mind this is code that runs for 20+ years with no reboots, so even a malloc/new of a few bytes will kill you over time, or you have to write a memory manager.

Comment: @Trampas well, if you can't use the heap because it's buggy, then the next options you have are:  create your own memory manager so that you remove the memory leak; or 2, just use the stack.  If you're just using the stack, you can't just free memory any time you want; that's not the way it works.  If you want it a static variable, then you have to have it created as a static instance.  I'd probably go with option 1 because not using heap is a fairly serious limitation.